# Menu Items not working when i hit menu items

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu, android-menu

i am implementing side navigation bar , i`ll create `onOptionsItemSelected`() method inside method codes are

`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
     if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))return true;

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logoutId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.homeId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.profileId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.settingsId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`

every thing is fine but clicking action not working.?  plz help me!!!

**update:**

[image: ActionBar Menu Item]
[image: Side Navigation Item]  not working!

Action bar item  worked well but

but Side Navigation Item not working! plz tell me the solution and why its not working ?

Comment: is onOptionsItemSelected called?

Comment: i use this method `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: `.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` doesn't inflate a menu. How do you inflate the menu?

Comment: oops! then i didn\`t make any calling method for `onOptionsItemSelected()` .  and how to call `onOptionsItemSelected()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should return true when you handle menu item click. Try to add the return statement on each case.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.logoutId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.homeId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.profileId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.settingsId:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , item.getItemId() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: I saw your update. If you used navigation view so I think you need to override onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) method, and in this method you need to write the switch case code.